# Что значит и как называется это отношение?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В VS увидел такое отношение, что оно значит и как называется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это один ко многим отношение, но оно обозначает, что поле связи этих таблиц может равняться null. Т.е. у Ninja не обязательно будет NinjaEquipment.

В запросах на выборку будет генерироваться не Inner Join, а Left Join.

Comment: А так же что у 1 Ninja может быть много NinjaEquipment